# what does 自己PR mean？

Tags: definitions

I keep coming across this word often 「自己PR」when looking at applications. I'm not sure what the "PR" part means in Japanese, but in English it usually means "public relations". What does this word mean, and what does the "PR" stand for?

Comment: http://howtojaponese.com/tag/%E8%87%AA%E5%B7%B1pr/ this seems to describe it pretty well: self-promotion or the way you advertise yourself in a professional setting.

Comment: Also know an 自己アピール. It is a chance for an applicant to "appeal" their personal characteristics and strengths.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The PR does indeed stand for public relations.　In English it is almost exclusively a business term used to represent a companies goals to persuade the public, employees, and other stakeholders to maintain a certain point of view about it, its leadership, products, etc.

In Japanese it has the same meaning, only it can be applied to areas other than business. In this case, 自己 (yourself). So in a sense, the phrase basically means your own personal PR.

Having written several CV's in Japanese I can tell you that it is basically the part of the CV where you get a chance to talk about yourself, your skills & abilities, etc in an attempt to persuade your employer about how awesome you are, and why they should hire you.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are familiar with cover letters, what the job candidate writes in a Jiko PR would be the equivalent of what she/he would write in 
a cover letter.